# How do I code this math script?

Tags: javascript

A script that would add 5 to 0 with every click. So if i click it once it would give me 5, twice 10, thrice 15 and so on.

```
function add5() {
  var originalNumber = 0
  var add5 = 5
  var el = document.getElementById('number');
  el.textContent = originalNumber + add5;
}
var el = document.getElementById('number');
el.textContent = originalNumber;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate method here. One way of doing this (using es6 and css to display the value):

```js
"use strict";
(() => {
  const report = document.querySelector('[data-value]');
  document.querySelector('#add5')
    .addEventListener(
      'click',
      () => report.setAttribute('data-value', +report.getAttribute('data-value') + 5)
      //                                      ^convert value to Number
  );
})();
```

```css
[data-value]:after {
  content: attr(data-value);
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="number">
  your value now: <span data-value="0"></span> 
  <button id="add5">Add 5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign original number to the old number
you have many ways to do it

1-

```
el.textContent = originalNumber = originalNumber + add5;
```

2-

```
el.textContent = 0;
el.textContent += add5;
```

Answer (score 0):

On every click Get the value in your element and add 5 to it .

That means change this line

`el.textContent = originalNumber + add5;`

To this

`el.textContent = parseInt(el.textContent ,10)+ add5;`

**Note:**  since you fetch the number as a text content it will be in string format. To do any math operations it is better to convert any string format numbers to actual numbers. Hence I have used `parseInt` to convert the text number to integer

Also you can remove the line `var originalNumber = 0` within the function. It has no effect after you make the above change

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, it may help you.

```js
originalNumber = 0
function add_5() {
  var el = document.getElementById('number');
    originalNumber = parseInt(el.textContent);
    var add5 = 5 
el.textContent = originalNumber + add5;
}
var el = document.getElementById('number');
el.textContent = originalNumber ;
```

```html
<div id="number" onclick="return add_5();" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like this:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
     <body>
      <button id="add" onclick="add5()">Add 5</button>
      <span id="output">Output: 0</span>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var sum = 0;
      function add5(){
        sum += 5;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Output: '+sum;
      }
     </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Now every time when you click on button it add 5 to your Output.

Answer (score 0):

It would only add 5 to an original variable initialized at 0, inside a function that will be called with the `onClick` event

```js
var originalNumber =0;
function add5() {
  var el = document.getElementById('number');
  el.textContent= originalNumber+=5;
}
```

```css
#number{
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      background: #ca2;
    }
```

```html
<div id="number" onclick="return add5();"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following is a fairly decent way to achieve what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div id="number">0</div>
```

**JS**

```
var numberElement = document.getElementById('number');
numberElement.addEventListener('click',function(event){ // Add an event handler to numberElement 
    var el = event.target; // Find out which element was clicked
    originalNumber = parseInt(el.textContent); // Parse string into a number (use parseFloat if you want to handle decimals)
  el.textContent = originalNumber + 5 // Update the textContent of the element
});
```

Note: why `textContent` should be parsed is it returns a string so it's to ensure expected behavior if the `textContent` of the `div` was set to `"05"` - `"05" + 5 === "055"` not the expected 10